Share code across sagemaker pipeline steps without
I am trying to create Sagemaker pipeline with multiple steps. I have some code which I would like to share across different steps. Next example is not exact but simplified version for illustration.
I have folder structure which looks next:
source_scripts/
├── utils
│   ├── logger.py
├── models/
│   ├── ground_truth.py
│   ├── document.py
├── processing/
│   ├── processing.py
│   └── main.py
└── training/
    ├── training.py
    └── main.py


I would like to use code from models and utils inside training.py as I don't know where exactly code mounted on Sagemaker instance I am using:
from ..common.ground_truth import GroundTruthRow

As I am building pipeline I create processing and training step:
script_processor = FrameworkProcessor()
args = script_processor.get_run_args(
    source_dir="source_scripts"
    code="processing/main.py"
)
step_process = ProcessingStep(
    code=args.code
)

estimator = Estimator(
    source_dir="source_scripts"
    code="training/main.py"
)
step_train = TrainingStep(
   estimator=estimator
)

But during pipeline execution it results in error:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Any suggestions how to share code across several SageMaker jobs in single pipeline without building custom docker image?

First of all, based on documentation, if you use sagemaker.estimator.Estimator you need to provide an image_uri value. As for the import statement, can you try to do from source_scripts.models.ground_truth import GroundTruthRow.

Also, why not use dependencies argument instead of specifying source_dir to import all files? You can do source_dir=training and pass dependencies=["source_scripts/models", "source_scripts/utils"], then you can do from models.ground_truth import GroundTruthRow

Thank you @FranciscoParrilla I will take a look at dependencies. Regards images - I use AWS stock images and would like to evade need to build my own (however I think I will end up there anyway)

Something I do when using my own images, is that i don't use Estimator class with them, instead I use framework classes instead. For example, Tensorflow(), and i passed my image uri with packaged dependencies, etc, however, I don't package my entry point here, i pass it through entry_point, so I can change it as i need without packaging it up again and uploading, etc. Hope it helps.

Quickest solution for this issue is to move the entry point scripts (processing/main.py, training/main.py) to the upper level directly under "source_scripts/" like this:
source_scripts/
├── utils
│   └── logger.py
├── models/
│   ├── ground_truth.py
│   └── document.py
├── processing_main.py
└── training_main.py

and avoid using relative import with .. in the entry point scripts.
from models.ground_truth import GroundTruthRow

The reason why you see the ImportError is because the entry point script's __name__ variable doesn't have package structure information unlike other modules.
If you print __name__ in models.ground_truth.py, you would see something like models.ground_truth and it contains package structure. But if you print __name__ in training/main.py, you see __main__, so Python cannot understand how to handle ...
If you need to keep the current directory structure, there may be more complicated solutions, but moving entry point files to upper level would be simplest.
Also, I recommend testing the solution in your handy local Python environment before running your SageMaker Pipeline.

I actually tried this before asking here, and there is still one shortcoming, you can't import anything from logger.py inside document.py.  I even tried to ship init.py along training_main.py and as I know that inside container it is copied into /ml/opt/code refer root package as code but it didn't work either.
